# API for monetary transactions

Tags: node.js, braintree, venmo

I am doing a project where users should be able to send money to one another. I had originally planned on creating Venmo transactions. I am reading through the developer docs but I am having trouble obtaining an Access Token from the Venmo website. I am also looking at the Braintree developer docs and everything seems geared towards merchants, which is not my use case.

Does anyone know if it is possible to create Venmo transactions and how?

Comment: pls accept the answer if it solve your problem or still have problem then update me

Answer (score 1):

venmo node module
Installing
To install venmo.js from npm

```
npm install venmo
```

**Payment Links API**

The Payment Links API is a simple interface for generating urls to serve as the entry point to make a Venmo payment or charge. Using it with venmo.js is quite straightforward. `First, you'll need to register your app with Venmo.` Then, start creating payment links:

```
var Venmo = require('venmo')


, venmo = new Venmo(client_id, client_secret)

var object = {
    user: 'user_name'
  , amount: 1000
};

venmo.pay(object, function (error, link) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log(link) # => https://venmo.com/user_name?txn=pay&amount=1000
  }

});
```

[For more detail see module documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/venmo)

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it seems that Venmo is no longer allowing users to register new apps.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

From the Braintree documentation:

> Venmo payments are currently in a limited release and are only available to select merchants with our iOS v4 SDK or Android v2 SDK in the US.<sup>[1](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/venmo/overview#limited-release-eligibility)</sup>

You can confirm whether your business model is eligible to participate in the [limited release here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/venmo/overview#limited-release-eligibility). You will note that, at the time of this answer, facilitating peer-to-peer transactions between two Venmo users is not a supported use case.

If you've been accepted to the limited release, you can walk through the [client-side](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/venmo/client-side/ios/v4) and [server-side](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/venmo/server-side/ios/v4) documentation to get your integration functioning.